# Implementing Spring Integration InboundChannelAdapter for Kafka

Tags: java, spring-integration, apache-kafka

I am trying to implement a custom inbound channel adapter in spring integration to consume messages from [apache kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/). Based on spring integration examples, I found that I need to create a class that implements MessageSource interface and implement receive() method that would return consumed Message from kafka. But based on [consumer example in kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart.html), the message iterator in KafkaStream is backed by a BlockingQueue. So if no messages are in the queue, the thread will be blocked.

So what is the best way to implement a receive() method as this method can potentially block until there is something to consume.. ?

In more general sense, How do we implement a custom inbound channel for streaming message sources that blocks until there is something ready to consume..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The receive() method can block (as long as the underlying operation responds properly to an interrupted thread), and from an inbound-channel-adapter perspective, depending on the expectations of the underlying source, it might be preferable to use a fixed-delay trigger. For example, "long polling" can simulate event-driven behavior when a very small delay value is provided.

We have a similar situation in our JMS polling MessageSource implementation. There, the underlying behavior is handled by one of the JmsTemplate's receive() methods. The JmsTemplate itself allows configuration of a timeout value. That means, as an example, you may choose to block for 5-seconds max but then have a very short delay trigger between each blocking receive call. Alternatively, you can specify an indefinite receive timeout. The decision ultimately depends on the expectations of the underlying resource, message throughput, etc.

Also, I wanted to let you know that we are exploring Kafka adapters ourselves. Perhaps you would like to collaborate on this within the spring-integration-extensions repository?

Regards,
Mark

Comment: Thanks @mfisher , How to can I contact you to discuss about collaborating with spring-integration-extensions repository..?